# How to remove a huge amount of files from repo with git?

Tags: git

I try to remove files from a local git repo with:

```
ls dataset/82146_images/train/labels/*.png | xargs git rm
```

but the list of arguments is too long:

```
$ ls dataset/82146_images/train/labels/*.png | xargs git rmbash: /bin/ls: Liste d'arguments trop longue
usage : git rm [<options>] [--] <fichier>...

    -n, --dry-run         simuler l'action
    -q, --quiet           ne pas afficher les fichiers supprimés
    --cached              supprimer seulement de l'index
    -f, --force           outrepasser la vérification des fichiers à jour
    -r                    autoriser la suppression récursive
    --ignore-unmatch      sortir avec un statut zéro même si rien ne correspondait
```

I also try:

```
$ git rm -r dataset/82146_images/train/labels
```

but the prompt seems to stay stucked forever ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is occurring inside the shell (`bash`) itself, and has little to do with Git.  Fortunately there is a solution that involves using Git directly. :-)

This:

```
ls dataset/82146_images/train/labels/*.png
```

is a request to the *shell* to find, in the one named directory, all<sup>1</sup> files whose names end with `.png`.  The shell will examine the directory, find all such files, and turn them into individual arguments to the `ls` command.  For instance, if there were just three such files, `a.png` and `b.png`, this would do exactly the same thing as:

```
ls dataset/82146_images/train/labels/a.png dataset/82146_images/train/labels/b.png
```

The process of having the shell expand names like this is called [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

But, because there are so many files, the *shell itself* runs out of space to expand all the names *before* it can run `ls`.

Fortunately, there is no need to use the *shell* to expand all the names, because Git has the same globbing built-in.  You can simply give:

```
dataset/82146_images/train/labels/*.png
```

directly to `git rm` itself.  The trick is that you must *protect the asterisk (`*`) from the shell*, i.e., make the shell *not* glob-expand it:

```
git rm 'dataset/82146_images/train/labels/*.png'
```

Whether to use single or double quotes is somewhat shell-dependent; in bash, both do the same thing for this case, but single quotes also protect against `$` and several other expansion actions, while double quotes protect only against globbing—`$` expansion still occurs.

(Not all Unix-ish programs—in fact, very few—do this kind of glob expansion.  In fact, since the shell will, *most* such programs *won't*.  Git makes an exception for many reasons, including the fact that it kind of has to for `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files, for instance.)

This removal may take a long time!  Note that:

```
git rm -r dataset/82146_images/train/labels
```

asks Git to recursively remove *all* files and directories in `dataset/82146_images/train/labels`, i.e., not just top-level files named `*.png`, so this might remove even more files than `*.png` would, but if `git rm -r` is taking a long time, so will the glob-expanding `git rm`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, `*.png` matches only files whose name does not start with a literal period `.`.  That is, if there are files named `a.png`, `b.png`, and `.hidden.png`, this matches `a.png` and `b.png` but not `.hidden.png`.